# How to simplify a quotient with exponents (using power rules)

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I'm trying to simplify the following expression

```
(b (1 - x)^n (-1 + x)^-n (-1 + x - w x)^n)/(n (-1 + w) (1 - x + w x)).
```

All parameters and the variable x should be positive real numbers. As far as I can see, this can't be simplified further with Simplify or FullSimplify. I know that the simplified expression is

```
(b*(1 + (-1 + w)*x)^(-1 + n))/(n*(-1 + w))
```

but I'd like to know how to 'automate' this kind of simplification with Mathematica's functions, if possible.

Comment: `(1 - x)^n (-1 + x)^-n` will only simplify to `-1` if `n` is an integer. You might want to re-examine your assumptions. In any event, look up `Assuming[]`.

Comment: Yes, it's true that n is an integer -- sorry, should have added that.

Comment: Are you sure about the simplified form? I get `(b*(1 + (-1 + w)*x)^(-1 + n))/(n*(-1 + w))`

Comment: No, I've now realised that my 'simplified form' was indeed the wrong expression.  I agree that your solution is correct (and see Answer below).  Thanks for your help.   [*** note I've edited the question above to correct it]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
expr = (b (1 - x)^n (-1 + x)^-n (-1 + x - w x)^n)/(n (-1 + w) (1 - x + w x));
```

Your stated assumptions including your comment

```
assume = {Thread[Variables@Level[expr, {-1}] > 0], Element[n, Integers]} // 
  Flatten
```

> {b > 0, n > 0, w > 0, x > 0, n \[Element] Integers}

The simplified expression is

```
expr // Simplify[#, assume] &
```

> (b (1 + (-1 + w) x)^(-1 + n))/(n (-1 + w))

Comparing with your presumed simplification

```
expr == b/(n (1 - w)) (1 - (1 - x + w x)^(n - 1)) // Simplify[#, assume] &
```

> False

Consequently, the presumed simplification is not equal to the original expression under the given assumptions.

Comment: Yes, this is correct.  I mistakenly pasted the wrong 'presumed simplification', and now I see that the result here is what I'm looking for.  Thanks very much.    [*** note I've edited the question above to correct it]